# Start Firefox in fullscreen with no easy way to exit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, kiosk, web-application

I would like Firefox to start automaticaly in fullscreen mode and with no menus, tabs, etc...

It's for an app, and the users should not be able to easily exit the app.

Comment: You most likely can't. But what you're looking for is called "kiosk mode".

Comment: Are you talking about locally? You have firefox and you want it to start in kiosk mode with a specific webpage and no easy way to exit?

Comment: Are you talking about a separate computer that should run in kiosk mode or some on the fly demo on a system otherwise used for normal purposes? If former I'd recommend a solution without gdm/gnome and starting the x server and firefox directly via init script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around your problem is to use a script(like [this](http://michkhoo.blogspot.com/2011/01/kiosk-mode-with-ubuntu-xubuntu.html)  kiosk script uses) that would reopen firefox whenever it is closed.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

The 30 characters strong answer is: `firefox --kiosk https://yourweb.site`